# Create MVC estructure from consolidate file(s)

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have created a web application that acts as a repository of information entered by specific forms. Lets say If a want to store geolocations then I create the following structure in the application in order to manage it:

1. Create a db table to store the geolocations
2. Create model that represent this table (I am using Doctrine2 as ORM)
3. Create a controller to manage and validate data entered by the user in browser
4. Create a view with the html form that contains "latitude" and "longitude" inputs.

About the model representation, its structure is mapped in a xml and a php objet like this:

PHP class:

```
namespace models;

class Geolocation{

    protected $id;
    protected $latitude;
    protected $longitude;

    public function __construct($latitude, $longitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }
}
```

XML object map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                      http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="models\Geolocation" table="geolocation">


    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id_geolocation">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>

    <field name="latitude" column="latitude" type="integer" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="longitude" column="longitude" type="integer" nullable="false"/>


</entity>
```

The structure above is just one entity in the application, there are "persons", "pets", "fruits", etc. Until now always has been easy for me to create every component (model, table, view, controller) manually, because the  application growth flow was relative slow. Today I woke up and I wanted to fall back by the amount of new repositories that I need to create since the application is getting bigger.

So, I was thinking in create a new application that can create all of these elements dynamically from a consolidated file like an XML. Then, apply some XSLT and/or php logic  in order to generate the the model, view, table, and why not the controller. Maybe something like this:

```
<repository>
    <name>Geolocation</name>
    <table>geolocation_table</table>
    <fields>
        <field name="latitude" column="latitude" type="integer" nullable="false" input="text" style="text-large">
            <rules>required, integer</rules>
        </field>
        <field name="longitude" column="longitude" type="integer" nullable="false" input="text" style="text-large">
            <rules>required, integer</rules>
        </field>
    </fields>
</repository>
```

But before to get get started with this new challenge, I would like to know if exists and application that can reproduces *something similar* like this. I know this concern sounds like a "do-everything-itself", yes, but what I really want to avoid is reinvent the warm water. If not, ok, I will create it from scratch if is necessary.

Just for reference purposes I am using these tools:

- Laravel 4: Controllers and views
- Doctrine 2: Models and persistence
- Twitter Bootstrap: To style html elements in forms at views.

PS: the title is so ambiguous, please correct me as required.

**Edit**

Looks like I am pointing to very similar module called [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) of Yii Framework

Comment: What is your concrete programming question here? Please take note that asking for an existing library suggestion is off-topic on Stackoverflow. You need to formulate that as a concrete programming question. Your question so far seems pretty broad and unclear (apart from asking: which library does this).

Comment: Of course, I agree with you, even I tried to focus in seek for a terminology to help me how to start programming this new application instead of a ask for "which library does this", thrust me, avoiding the off-topic sence was priority for me.

Comment: Well, you're not asking for terminology clarfication here, at least I don't see that. You don't show what your research about the terminilogy has resulted in so far. Instead you list technologies you use as if there would be a deeper meaning in those technologies - which most often never is.

Comment: And you most certainly never create an MVC structure from a single consolidate file. MVC is about the separation of concerns, so M and V and C differ - for you it's the same, totally consolidated. Therefore MVC - as imprecise the term in itself is already normally used - is totall off the field in your question. Far away from terminilogy finding - but I already commented on that. Just saying.

Comment: Well, I am just exposing here and scenario based in my knowledge and of course, I could be lost in some technical terms handling, but, the question is not easy to create neither. Here are people that ask "how can I create a -hello world- in jquery?", as this question is so simple that people does not bad an eye. But please, don't take it by the wrong way, not discussion is necessary, and if the question is not clear I could reformulate it.

Comment: Yes I can perfectly understand that. But it's perhaps more worth to look more into terminology and keep the technogoly part exemplary. I know it's hard to just simply ask for what one want to know. Sometimes rewording from scratch a second time can help.